# Merging two datasets, one has 4000 and another has 864000 rows

Tags: python

One dataset has 4000 observations for 7 features while the other dataset has 864000 observations for 5 features. How to merge these two datasets?

Is down sampling or up sampling a option? Like so:

```
df2_sampled = df2.sample(n = 4000, random_state = 42)
```

Please help regarding this.
Above datasets are from a bank, they want to launch a new credit card.

I tried down sampling the larger dataset(864000) but the 'customer id' column was not similar to the one in smaller dataset(4000). So, what approach is to be taken?

Comment: Without knowing, how these datasets are related we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search I found the Pandas user guide (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html), which mentions using `pd.concat()` to merge DataFrame objects in Pandas.

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)
```

The above would return a DataFrame containing `df1` and `df2` containing all the data from both DataFrames, with all datapoints without a known value represented as `NaN` (this would apply to the last 3 columns 4-column dataset).

Alternatively, you could perform a merge with `df1.merge(df2)`.

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='IDENTIFIER', how='left')
```

This would create a DataFrame of both your existing datasets merged with `IDENTIFIER` being some shared column.

Comment: thank you buddy. I'll implement your suggestion.

Comment: Please consider marking this answer as accepted so that future readers can find it more easily.